# I want to create component of navigation and called it in app.js in react but navigation component is not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was creating a component of navigation and calling this in app.js but the component is showing an error is navigation is defined but not used.
[navigation.js screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHoXz.png)

[index.js screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw5O8.png)

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJER6.png)

code of app.js is

```
import { navigation } from "./components/navigation";

 import React from "react";

  function App() 

  {

return(
    
    <>
      <navigation/>
    </>
)
   }
    export default App;
```

Comment: That's not an error rather just a warning though

Answer (score 0):

All React components should start with a capital letter.

You should change your **navigation.js** to **Navigation.js**